# Customize Bluetooth LE beacon broadcasts

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The iBeacon broadcasts RSSI (radio signal strength) for the receiver to gauge the proximity. Instead of broadcasting RSSI, can the broadcast payload be customized to send sensor data such as temperature and humidity? If yes, how can the TI CC2540 beacon be modified to support this function?

Comment: To be clear on terminology, a "beacon" is supposed to be used to determine physical proximity, hence sending RSSI. "iBeacon" is Apple's trademark name for a beacon.  iBeacon is a particular LE service, with a known UUID that provides RSSI as the data payload. With LE you can advertise whatever service with whatever characteristic you like (within packet-size restrictions), but then you no longer have a beacon. You certainly shouldn't advertise an Apple iBeacon service UUID with non-RSSI data - make an new UUID: http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/uuid.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  :)

The LE advertising packet has a field for arbitrary data in EIR format (look in the [bluetooth spec](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737) for details).  The packet always contains the RSSI value, though, and you can't remove that.

As for modifying the CC2540, you may have to use the IAR compiler to modify the firmware.  There may be some specific cases where you can make the change without the compiler, but you didn't specify what device you had.  If it's the SensorTag, you may be able to modify it without the IAR compiler, but you'd have to look that up yourself on their wiki.